# How to convert bytearray into a zip file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a bytearray object in Python 2.7 that I got from a query to an SQL server and I know that it is a zip file. What I need to do now is access the data in the zip file.

How can I convert the bytearray into the file and safe it to the hard disc?

How can I access the data in the zip file directly in Python?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "convert" it into a file: Write the bytearray to disk without changing anything (be sure to open the file for writing with "wb"). To access its content without saving to disk, embed it into a `stringio` object (which mimics an open file) and access it with `zipfile`.